# django-parler: edit all translations for a field in a TranslatableModelForm

Tags: python, django, internationalization

I use the `django-parler` plugin to manage the translations of a certain model field. I have a [`TranslatableModelForm`](http://django-parler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/parler.forms.html?#the-translatablemodelform-class) through which I can edit instances of a certain `TranslatableModel`. This model has one translatable field defined as follows:

```
translations = TranslatedFields(
    description=models.TextField(null=True, blank=True),
)
```

Default behavior of this model form is to edit the description in a specific language. Is there a clean way to edit the translations for this field simultaneously without writing custom code? In other words, the model form would render and process a field for each configured language ("Description (EN)", "Description (FR)", etc) instead of merely a "Description" field.